# scale table in width and height

Tags: html, css, html-table

i've got a table 3x3 with Images in it. I want the table to scale with the windows width and height.

scaleing with the width is not a problem and working so far, but i don't get it working with the height. The aim is to see the whole table with no gaps between the images. Also the table should stop growing if the images are at 100% so no forced 100%.
is this possible in CSS only?

thanks for your help

that is what i got so far:

```
  <head>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0;padding: 0; line-height: 0;}
      html, body
      {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #imgHolder {
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
        height: auto;
        width:auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      img {
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="imgHolder">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td><td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td><td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td><td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td><td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td><td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td><td><img src="https://www.lionkeen.net/assets/img/cat.jpg" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xhaqzzkj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do window height, use viewport height `vh`, such as `100vh` or `98vh`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length
- https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

and use `calc()` with it, such as `calc(100vh - 16px)`, assuming you are using a modern browser.

Since you also have this requirement:

> Also the table should stop growing if the images are at 100% so no forced 100%

Do you mean if the images are not that big, don't force them to become big just to make the table 100% of viewport width and height?

If so it seems like you can have a table that contains these images, but have a `max-width` and `max-height` as `100vw` and `100vh`, respectively.

Or you can make the `td` and images have `max-width: 33vw` and `max-height: 33vh` like the following samples: https://jsfiddle.net/xhaqzzkj/7 and https://jsfiddle.net/xhaqzzkj/8

Comment: i don't get how that solves my problem could you please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: unfurtunately thats not working. Please see my jsfiddle. I want the same behavior that is now working with width but with the height in cojunction.

Comment: how about like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xhaqzzkj/2/ or https://jsfiddle.net/xhaqzzkj/3/  It was strange when I set a `max-height` on that table (the id), I see the max-height value in dev tool but the height was much bigger that the max-height (height exceeding max-height)

Comment: As written it shouldn't be just 100%, that should only be the maximum, also i want to preserve the image proposition

Comment: If it is to fill up both x and y, then it is https://jsfiddle.net/xhaqzzkj/6/ except it won't shrink to fit.  To shrink to fit: https://jsfiddle.net/xhaqzzkj/7/ and https://jsfiddle.net/xhaqzzkj/8/ but it has the disadvantage of, it might fill up either x or y but not both when the image is bigger

Comment: example 7 and 8 are exactly what i was searching for, thank you very much! can you edit your answer? than i will mark it as accepted. thanks again!